# bxslider trouble making responsive 100% width

Tags: jquery, css, carousel, bxslider

Im trying out different carousels(jcarousel,bxslider,owl carousel 2).. right now Im using bxslider, but I have trouble making it responsive.

Url: http://topforexbroker.net/hund/

bxslider options (http://bxslider.com/options):

```
                minSlides: 1,
                moveSlides:1,
                maxSlides: 8,
                slideWidth: 275,
                slideMargin: 10,
                pager: false
```

Preview on mobile:
[image: preview on mobile]

If I increase the slideWidth, it will look okay on mobile but then on my desktop it will mess up.

Any idea how to solve this? I actually got owl carousel 2 to work just like I wanted it to but for some reason when I slide I get a white background and it has to load the image I think it is called smooth scrolling correct me if Im wrong. Maybe Im using the wrong carousel for my intention?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to adjust the width of the div class card using media queries

Comment: Hi Lucky Chingi, thanks for your reply! Could you give me one more hint? If I increase the height of my card class to e.g. 335px looks okay my card-action goes away then I have to increase the bx-viewport height to 516px. I doubt this is the correct way of doing it but maybe it is.

Comment: I would suggest increasing the width of the class 'card' to match the minimum width of the screen on mobile, so that only one image is visible. OR use jQuery to switch MaxSlides to 1 on mobile screen

Comment: So on my card class you would add something like min-width:100%; ?

Comment: I changed back to the owl carousel 2.. Maybe someone could tell me why every slide element has to load, as I wrote in my first post: "I actually got owl carousel 2 to work just like I wanted it to but for some reason when I slide I get a white background and it has to load the image I think it is called smooth scrolling correct me if Im wrong."

Comment: which browser are you testing, The images dont load in FF

Comment: See it in action: https://i.gyazo.com/f98242476aba958217e3e2084b9d9cc7.gif

Answer (score 0):

I am not watching any bug in your page 
[image]

Anyways I am seeing that you define a width for each slide that is the cause of the issue.
Please remove slideWidth.
You can read more [here](http://bxslider.com/options)